# Developing a web bot crawler system after clustering the bots

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to identifying high hitting IP's over a duration of time.

I have performed clustering on certain features, got a 12 cluster output, out of which 8 were bots and 4 were humans, as per the centroid values of the cluster.

Now What technique can I use to analyze the data within the cluster, so as to know that the data points within the cluster are in the right clusters.

In other words, are there any statistical methods to check the quality of the clusters.?

What I can think of is , if I take a data point which is at the boundary of the cluster, If I measure the distance of this point from the other Centroids and from its own Centroid, then can I get to know how close the two clusters are to my point and may be  how well are my data divided in cluster ??

Kindly guide how to measure the quality of my clusters, with respect to data points and what are the standard technique to do so.

Thanks in Advance.!!
Cheers.!

Answer (score 0):

With k-means, the chances are that you already have a big heap of garbage. Because it is an incredibly crude heuristic, and unless you were extremely careful at designing your features (at which point you would already know how to check the quality of a cluster assignment) the result is barely better than choosing a few centroids at random. In particular with k-means, which is very sensitive to the scale of your features. The results are very unreliable if you have features of different types and scale (e.g. height, shoe size, body mass, BMI: k-means on such variables is statistical nonsense).

Do *not* dump your data into a clustering algorithm and expect to get something useful. Clustering follows the GIGO principle: garbage-in-garbage-out. Instead, you need to proceed as follows:

1. identify what is a good cluster *in your domain*. This is very data and problem dependant.
2. choose a clustering algorithm with a very simialar objective.
3. find a data transformation, distance function or *modification* of the clustering algorithm to align with *your* objective
4. carefully double-check the result for trivial, unwanted, biased and random solutions.

For example, if you blindly threw customer data into  clustering algorithm, the chances are it will decide the best answer to be 2 clusters, corresponding to the attributes "gender=m" and "gender=f"simply because this is the most extreme factor in your data. But because this is a know attribute, this result is entirely useless.

Comment: Hi Anony, but if I use scree plot to find the value of  K in K-means, then the value of K depends upon the data set which I am using. Once I find the right K, then I can run K-means to cluster the data points. Then I will evaluate each cluster and check if the homogeneity of the data points , within each cluster, as per my requirement. Does this idea sound correct to you.??!!

Comment: If course it depends on the data set, and there is a best-of-the-garbage solution. The problem with k-means is that it *will* return a result, even when it did not work well. **Check the k-means objective function**, does it make sense on your data and *attributes* (you didn't mention what attributes you used... but e.g. IP addresses can be used as 'numbers', but are meaningless)?